# Javascript page load time calculation returns negative

Tags: javascript, performance

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
// jQuery has already been loaded but this could be equivalent to 
// a function in <body onLoad="">
$(function(){
  var iNavStart=performance.timing.navigationStart;
  var iNavEnd=performance.timing.loadEventEnd;
  var iPageLoad=iNavEnd-iNavStart;
  console.dir({'iNavStart',iNavStart});
  console.dir({'iNavEnd',iNavEnd});
  console.dir({'iPageLoad',iPageLoad});
});
//]]</script>
```

When the page loads, the console reveals:

```
iNavStart: 1449594976150
iNavEnd:   0
iPageLoad: -1449594976150
```

I was expecting this calculation to give me a nice number of milliseconds. Surely *iNavEnd* shouldn't be *0*?

Tested in Chrome 47 and Firefox 42 (both support *performance.timing*).

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that [Ionut Popa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/386085/ionut-popa) [answers this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11048634) on Stackoverflow in [Measuring Site Load Times via performance api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606972/measuring-site-load-times-via-performance-api):

> You need to measure the loadEventEnd after the onload event has finished or else it will be reported as 0, as never happened. (jquery example for attaching to the onload event)
>
> ```
> $(window).load(function(){
>  setTimeout(function(){
>  window.performance = window.performance || window.mozPerformance || window.msPerformance || window.webkitPerformance || {};
>  var timing = performance.timing || {};
>  var parseTime = timing.loadEventEnd - timing.responseEnd;
>  console.log('Parsetime: ', parseTime);
>  }, 0);
> });
> ```

Comment: Thanks Stephen, its the setTimeout part I was missing that makes all the difference!